# Autocomplete Twig function parameters in PhpStorm

Tags: php, symfony, twig, phpstorm

I am using a custom Twig function to determine the current user's access rights to some route. For that I'd like to have autocompletion for available routes, when using the function:
`{{ isAllowed('app_backend_...') }}`.
Built-in Symfony plugin already provides that for
`{{ path('app_backend_...) }}` for example.

I've tried setting it up in both ways described in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/symfony-creating-helper-functions.html#method-parameter

The competition is working in the PHP code (`$appExtension->isAllowed('app_backend_...')`), but not in Twig (as described above).

Am I missing something?

Setup:
PhpStorm 2019.1.2
Symfony Plugin 0.17.172 incl. Twig Support

Comment: I couldn't get that working either. So instead I made an XDebug thing for Twig. If you use XDebug, you'll like this. https://github.com/delboy1978uk/twig-debug

Comment: Just wondering if this is what are you looking for: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-28093

Comment: @delboy1978uk I don't really get, how debug output (possibly in the browser?) could help in this situation. Could you explain that some more? As a work-around I create the path using the Twig function path btw (which has autocomplete) and replace the function name afterwards

Comment: @user10550971 The topic seems to be about completion for variable and method names. What I am looking for though is auto completion for a string. This string can only have certain values, which are determined by the routes actually available in the project.